# Custom paging issue

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am creating a custom paging solution but i am struggling with coming up wiht an algorithym to solve the problem.

I need to create an  of index positions e.g. *1* 2 3 4 5 (where *1* represents the selected index). This obviosuly becomes more complex when you take into account that i will need to apply an upper boundry so for example if there are 10 pages and the current selected index is 8 I would like the  to contain 6 7 *8* 9 10.  If we where then to select the last page the  would become 6 7 8 9 *10*.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction for this? I am struggling to know exactly what i can even search for to find the answers.

Comment: Try searching on 'pagination' here. It returns tons of results (which you should have seen above your question as you typed it). Surely one of them would have helped point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it. It is quite similar to [Kyle's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720187/custom-paging-issue/5720320#5720320) except it uses extension methods and it does not fail when the pages to display is higher than the total number of pages.

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetDisplayedPages(int currentPage, 
                                          int totalPages, 
                                          int pagesToDisplay)
{
    if (totalPages <= pagesToDisplay) {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, totalPages);

    } else {
        if (pagesToDisplay % 2 == 1) pagesToDisplay -= 1;

        if (currentPage - (pagesToDisplay / 2) <= 0) {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, pagesToDisplay + 1);
        } else if (currentPage + (pagesToDisplay / 2) >= totalPages) {
            return Enumerable.Range(totalPages - pagesToDisplay, pagesToDisplay + 1);
        } else {
            return Enumerable.Range(Convert.ToInt32(currentPage - (pagesToDisplay / 2)), pagesToDisplay + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, worked for me. I just modified the returned page to also show a "First" and "Last" link.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but you should get the drift. Basically, you just have to make sure to iterate correctly taking into account the starting/stopping points using that if-else-if-else logic

```
public List<int> GetIndices(int min, int current, int count, int max)
{
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    int half = count / 2

    if(current - (half) < min)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count && i < max; i++)
        {
            indexes.add(i);
        }
    }
    else if(current + (half) > max)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count && max - i > 0; i++)
        {
            indexes.add(max - i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            indexes.add(current - half + i)
        }
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a total of `indexTotal` (10 in your case) and a displayable amount of `indexDisplay` (5) you may calculate the following:

```
firstIndex = max(1, selectedIndex - indexDisplay/2);
lastIndex = firstIndex + indexDisplay - 1;
if (lastIndex > indexTotal) {
    lastIndex = indexTotal;
    firstIndex = max(1, lastIndex - indexDisplay + 1);
}
```

e.g.

- `selectedIndex = 1` yields `firstIndex = 1; lastIndex = 5;`
- `selectedIndex = 8` yields `firstIndex = 6; lastIndex = 10;`
- `selectedIndex = 10` yields `firstIndex = 6; lastIndex = 10;`

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetIndices(int min, int current, int count, int max)
{
    int delta = current > max - count? current - (max - count) : count / 2;         
    int start = Math.Max(min, current - delta);
    int end = Math.Min(max, start + count);
    for (int i=start; i <= end; i++) yield return i;
}
```

or

```
List<int> GetIndices(int min, int current, int count, int max)
{   
    List<int> list = new List<int>();     
    int delta = current > max - count? current - (max - count) : count / 2;         
    int start = Math.Max(min, current - delta);
    int end = Math.Min(max, start + count);
    for (int i=start; i <= end; i++) list.Add(i);
    return list;
}
```

How this works - this is more or less the clamp function.  Given x, min, max, clamp(x, min, max) is x if x >= min and x <= max; min if x < min, max if x > max.  I figure out the start.  It's the current position less a delta.  The delta is count/2 **unless** the current is in the top count items, then it gets adjusted.  The end is start + count.  From there, it's iteration.